# How to run a function in a loop multiple times asynchronously in node.js using the async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am reading multiple google docs using the google-spreadsheet module. This involves looping through all of the credentials for each module I have saved in a json file and then pulling the spreadsheet. So if there are 10 spreadsheet credentials in my json file, I will need to within a loop call the function with these details, 10 times.

I will then save the information from these spreadsheets. I need to do this asynchronously. How can I achieve this, maybe using the async module? I tried to understand the queue aspect of this module but couldn't make much sense of it.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

    // All of the below could be put in a separate function that needs to be run asynchronously 

    var sheetID=sheets[i]
    // spreadsheet key is the long id in the sheets URL
    var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetID);

    doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
      }
      doc.getInfo(function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        sheet = info.worksheets[0];

        sheet.getRows({
         orderby: "marketname",
          start: 0
        }, function(err, row_data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < row_data.length; i++) {
            console.log(row_data[i].marketname);
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly what you want to do is an asynchronous for loop. This mean that you have an async treatment (here everything under your comment), that you need to chain together, one after another.

Without using the async lib, you can do it as in this example

```
// Async task
function async(arg, callback) {
  //You put in here what needs to be done with each of your data 
}
// Final task: display or save your data in your files
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }

// A simple async series:
var items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
var results = [];
//Recursive function that will go through your items.
function series(item) {
  //if there is still some item to work with
  if(item) {
    //call your async function with our current item
    async( item, function(result) {
      //push in the results
      results.push(result);
      //Go to the next item.
      return series(items.shift());
    });
  } else {
    //Otherwise this means we're done, and results[] is populated!
    return final();
  }
}
//Start the treatment
series(items.shift());
```

Hope this helps!

You can find more information about some control flow in [this great paper](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html).